# Generate new tensor based on another one and indices of the columns

Tags: python, tensorflow

Basically, i have a list of indices generated by `tf.random.uniform` and a tensor called `tensor_big`, now i need to create a new tensor `tensor_small` where inside are all the elements of the main tensor where the second coordinate is inside the `indices` list.

Example:

Indices = [1, ......]

Then i need to create a new tensor with the weights at position `[0,1], [1,1], [2,1]` etc for each indices.

```
import tensorflow as tf

if __name__ == '__main__':
    tensor_big = tf.random.uniform(
        (3136,512), minval=0, maxval=None, dtype=tf.dtypes.float32, seed=None, name=None
    )

    indices = tf.random.uniform(shape=[410, ], minval=0, maxval=512, dtype=tf.dtypes.int32, seed=None, name=None)
    for weight in tensor_big:
        print(weight[1])
    tensor_small = tf.reshape(tf.gather(tensor_big, WHERE_SECOND_COORDINATE_INSIDE_INDICES), (3136,410))

    print(tensor_small)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `tf.gather` with the argument `axis=1` to select the columns:

```py
tensor_small = tf.gather(tensor_big, indices, axis=1)
```

Comment: Oh, it was so easy, how didn't i see that? Thanks!